# Admob test Ads showing up on emulator but not a real phone ?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I am new to Unity, I created a simple app and added test ads to it, I tried to see if everything works fine in an emulator, ads wereshowing up but when I tried to see if ads are working in my phone things didnt work. the app works fine but the ads not.

I readed some answers for the same problem, I added a line to AndroitManifest.xml but nothing seems to work.

Some proposed that there is an issue with the size of the ads view, but I don"t think it is true, because I used the same things in others apps.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start
Sometimes the ads take more than an hour to load on phones when you make any change. Remove the Test ID so that you can load the ad on your phone or use the Test ID of your phone. https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads
Regards!